# "Gazebo GUI" is not responding when running spherical_coordinates.sdf world

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble

I am trying to run the world spherical_coordinates.sdf that comes as an example with gazebo.

I run ros humble on ubuntu22.04 and get this black screen and then error:

[image: error]

This is the code for the example if it is helpful:
[spherical_coordinates.sdf](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/examples/worlds/spherical_coordinates.sdf)

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to understand why it crashes